# RSpec No route matches {:action=>"/dashboard/sites/24/attendance_summer_city_camp_integrativ.xlsx", :controller=>"dashboard/sites"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a controller `/dashboard/sites_controller.rb`, within which I have an action `attendance_summer_city_camp_integrativ`

```
def attendance_summer_city_camp_integrativ
  @site = Site.find(params[:site_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.xlsx
  end
end
```

It returns an Excel, as you can see.

`config/routes.rb`

```
namespace :dashboard do
  resources :sites do
    get :attendance_summer_city_camp_integrativ
  end
end
```

In my test file, when I do a get request on this address I get

`No route matches {:action=>"/dashboard/sites/24/attendance_summer_city_camp_integrativ.xlsx", :controller=>"dashboard/sites"}`

```
describe 'GET #attendance_summer_city_camp_integrativ' do
  subject do
      get dashboard_site_attendance_summer_city_camp_integrativ_path(site.id, format: :xlsx)
    end
end
```

```
Failure/Error: get dashboard_site_attendance_summer_city_camp_integrativ_path(site.id, format: :xlsx)

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"/dashboard/sites/24/attendance_summer_city_camp_integrativ.xlsx", :controller=>"dashboard/sites"}
```

When I go to this address manually in the browser it works fine.

```
Started GET "/dashboard/sites/6/attendance_summer_city_camp_integrativ.xlsx" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-06-28 18:18:46 +0200
Processing by Dashboard::SitesController#attendance_summer_city_camp_integrativ as XLSX
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this:

```
describe 'GET #attendance_summer_city_camp_integrativ' do
  subject do
    get dashboard_site_attendance_summer_city_camp_integrativ_path(site.id, format: :xlsx)
  end
end
```

Should be more like this:

```
describe 'GET #attendance_summer_city_camp_integrativ' do
  subject do
    get attendance_summer_city_camp_integrativ, {site_id: site.id, format: :xlsx}
  end
end
```

(I guess, according to the [docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/controller-spec), you may need to form your params differently for rails 5 v. pre-rails 5.)

You have an `action` called `attendance_summer_city_camp_integrativ`, but your test is trying to call the action `/dashboard/sites/24/attendance_summer_city_camp_integrativ.xlsx`. Which isn't an action, but a fully-formed url. So, maybe calling `get dashboard_site_attendance_summer_city_camp_integrativ_path` instead of `get attendance_summer_city_camp_integrativ` is the issue?

Comment: It doesn't work. Same error message. I don't think I need to do that because when I click on a button to to download the Excel file it works. It also works when I go to the url  `/dashboard/sites/6/attendance_summer_city_camp_integrativ.xlsx`

Comment: It looks like I needed to add params: { site_id: site.id, format: :xlsx }

Comment: Like in my edited answer, yes? Are you still using `dashboard_site_attendance_summer_city_camp_integrativ_path`?

Comment: Yes, `get :dashboard_site_attendance_summer_city_camp_integrativ_path, params: { ... }`